# Heroku: how to read file?

Tags: swift, file, heroku, file-io, vapor

I have the following project layout (contracted):

```
project_root
└── Sources
    └── App
        ├── main.swift
        └── Models
            └── SQL
                └── createTables.sql
```

I'm trying to read the `createTables.sql` file at runtime but `FileManager.fileExists()` says it doesn't exist. I got the path by using `#file` in `main.swift`:

```
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file).deletingLastPathComponent().path + "/Models/SQL/createTables.sql"
```

Printing out the path, it seems to be correct.
I'm guessing that the source tree is inaccessible because of Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). How can I get around this and read the file at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drop.workdir` to get the project directory after compile time.

```
try String(contentsOfFile: drop.workDir + "Resources/SQL/createTables.sql")
```

Note I've also moved your file out of `Sources` and into `Resources`. Vapor's project layout isn't set in stone, but currently the rule appears to be that the former is for Swift files and the latter for ancillary files.